# How to make a specific template according number of nodes in a content type?

Tags: theming, panels

I have a content type article and I need a specific template for showing articles according the number of nodes.  If I have 2 nodes (content type article) I need to make a template, if I have 3 nodes (content type article) I need to make another template.  How do you suggest to make that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to swap template files with panels I only know how to modify the layout based on condition, sorry. here's a small little snippet i quickly wrote to display a different template based on the number of nodes inside of the content type. This should really be done with a custom module but I don't have time.

1. Make sure templates are in template folder under your theme and named correctly.
2. Copy paste snippet below into your `template.php` file.

   ```
   function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

   if($vars['type'] == 'article'){
        // set content type
        $content_type = 'article';

        // Count number of articles in article
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) amount 
                  FROM {node} n ".
                 "WHERE n.type = :type";
        $result = db_query($query, array(':type' => $content_type))->fetch();

        // get number of articles
        $articleCount = $result->amount;

        //specify template based on number of articles
        // one - is equal to _ and two -- is equal to __ for template file
        // No need to add `.tpl.php`
        if($articleCount == 1){
            $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__template1';
        }
        if($articleCount == 2){
            $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__template2';
        }
        if($articleCount == 3){
            $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__template3';
        }
        // ect.... you should make a dynamic loop here this is just basic logic.
      }
   }
   ```
3. Modify code to your liking
4. Clear Cache

Answer (score 0):

`count(node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'The_Content_Type')))` will give you the number of nodes of type `The_Content_Type`.

The @DMAC solution is right but since you need to do this in Panels module so I give you this solution. In Panels select *Selection rules* and *PHP Code*

[image]

Now use this code

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'The_Content_Type'));
 if(count($nodes) == 2)
     return TRUE;
 else 
     return False;
```

You can clone this *variant*   and replace `2` with `3` and modify the theme.